Extend Monitor Wirelessly Ubuntu 24.04
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 on my main computer. I have a Windows 11 laptop that I want to use as an external monitor when I'm working on my computer and need the extra screen space. After a quick search I discovered Gnome implemented a new feature that allows me to use RDP to extend my screen by creating a virtual screen on Ubuntu and sharing that over RDP. I've used the following command to set the RDP desktop sharing mode to 'extend' instead of 'mirror main':
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.remote-desktop.rdp screen-share-mode 'extend'   

When I connect via RDP, I get a black screen on my laptop (which, to my understanding, should be fine at this stage), but I can't see the virtual display that should be created on the 'Displays' settings screen back on my main computer. The next step, according to some guides on the internet, should be to place the virtual screen next to my display in the settings to enable it and it should just start working after that, but again I can't see any screen in the 'Displays' menu. I see some settings for my current screen, but nothing other than that.
Image of 'Displays' tab in the settings menu:

